# Accessing certain elements from the unique words/terms per document

Tags: r, tm

[this](https://markhneedham.com/blog/2016/04/11/r-tm-unique-wordsterms-per-document/) code gives the output as a matrix. But here the repeated words like `is,am, i` should be avoided. I just want a matrix containing `cool ,mark` and `neo4j`. I have tried with `grep("cool",tdm)`. It's not working here. Is there any alternative method?

```
output: tdm
       Docs
Terms   1 2
  am    2 0
  cool  0 2
  i     2 0
  is    0 2
  mark  2 0
  neo4j 0 2
```

Comment: So you want the `unique()` function?

Comment: Just use `as.matrix(TermDocumentMatrix(corpus))`. the wordlength in the example is set at 1, default is 3. Or change the 1 in the example to 3.

Comment: I think 'tdm = as.matrix(TermDocumentMatrix(corpus)) ' removes the stop words. Thats wht it returns 'cool , mark and neo4j'. If i want only cool or mark how to extract only that.

Comment: @phiver: In the sense if some one wants to know how many times the particular word occurs in each document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small example code based on your example.

```
library(tm)
text <- c("I am Mark I am Mark", "Neo4j is cool Neo4j is cool")
corpus <- VCorpus(VectorSource(text))

# wordLengths set to 3, basicly the default removes all words of length 1 and 2
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus, control = list(wordLengths = c(3, Inf)))
as.matrix(tdm)

# only words cool and mark
# create a dictionary
my_dict <- c("cool", "mark")
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus, control = list(dictionary = dict ))
as.matrix(tdm)
      Docs
Terms  1 2
  cool 0 2
  mark 2 0
```

Be careful with just transforming document term matrices into a normal matrix. That can eat up a lot of memory if you have a lot of text.

But looking at your questions you need to read up on text-mining.

Here is a start with [tidy text-mining](http://tidytextmining.com/index.html)

Here is info about text mining with [quanteda](https://quanteda.io/)

And read the [vignette of tm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/vignettes/tm.pdf)

And of course search SO for examples. A lot has already been answered in one way or another.